# Every time I click Health Kit in App Gallery Connect in Huawei Developer Console it keeps closing the page and I cannot apply for Health kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to embed health kit into my app following [this doc](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMS-Guides/apply_id-0000001050069756). But every time I try to open the huawei health kit, page opens, waits for the developer.huawei's response then keeps closing the page and returns to the main console. I have been struggling in this for a day. Can you please help me?
Here I can see the console and I can click the health kit:
[image: Developer Console Image]

but I cannot see the apply for health kit page
[image: health kit page]

I also looked all the agreements I don't see any problem.

Here it stucks and returns to the main page:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be resolved when the browser cookies will be cleared.

Comment: I only cleared the caches and return back to huawei console. Did login with verification again and finally, the page was reachable to apply for health kit. Thank you!!